# Change the terminal emulater neovim uses

Tags: neovim, terminal-buffer

Is there a way to change which terminal emulator `neovim` uses for its `:terminal` command? I am running `neovim` on Windows 10, and it used `cmd` by default; however, I would rather use [`cmder`](http://cmder.net/) or [another linux-style emulator](https://www.slant.co/topics/1552/~terminal-emulators-for-windows) if I can.

Answer (score 4):

Neovim uses its own internal terminal emulator for `:term`.  You can not change that (as far as I know).  The thing you can change is the command interpreter/shell that runs in that terminal.   See Wikipedia for the difference: [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) vs [Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command-line_interpreter).

You can start any command (that you have installed) in the terminal if you just specify it as the argument: `:terminal bash`

I don't know how to do that by default but you can read the docs in order to find out if that's possible: [`:help :terminal`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/various.html#:terminal).

Or you can define a custom command:

```
:command MyTerm terminal bash
```

If you instead want to start `cmder` in its own window from within Neovim just run `:!cmder &` (I suppose the `&` also works in windows?).

Comment: how does it determine which shell is launched? For me it's rather unsuccessfully trying to open `C:Program FilesGitusr^Hin^Hash.exe`

Comment: @CervEd Please read the help link I provided and also the help about 'shell'.

Comment: not exactly the most helpful comment in the world

Comment: for actual useful information on the various oddities that occurs with shell and term on windows, checkout this issue https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/16646